# cannot create maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to create maven project but failed. I use proxy in my network. I can reach "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" in browser. the error show:

> Could not resolve archetype
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the
>   configured repositories. Could not resolve artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out

I already create setting.xml and put to .m2 folder. the setting.xml contains:

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>  
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>idnproxy.myproxy.asia</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>c76266</username>
      <password>Password09</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|128.*.*.*|10.*.*.*|*.intranet.asia|*.group.local</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

this setting proxy, port, username and password same with setting in my browser and I can running internet. I assume that configuration is true. how to fix this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be settings.xml , not setting.xml

Or if you do want to use this setting.xml , from command line, point maven to this xml file

```
mvn -s Full_PATH_TO_setting.xml install
```

Comment: oh sorry for typo.. my file is settings.xml but still failed for create maven project. any solution? I also run your suggestion command but failed