# trying to create maven project getting this error

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
```

I have configured settings.xml and I have installed maven into eclipse and I have configured jdk also but could not solve the issue and I have added remote catalog also with http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml as calalog file but facing the same issue.

Comment: Try building your question like: 1) what are you trying to do (I am trying to create a new maven project). 2) what did you do (I ran the command `x y z...`). 3) what went wrong (I received this error: `...`).  4) format your code inserts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot create maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631509/cannot-create-maven-project)

Answer (score 1):

Maven is not able to reach its central [repo](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

If you are behind any proxy,
Please configure proxy in settings.xml

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>your_protocol</protocol>
      <host>your_host</host>
      <port>your_port</port>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
```